# How to install Windows 8.1 after Ubuntu? I want to dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, grub-efi

I currently have Ubuntu installed and an empty partition to install windows in (NTFS).

If I launch boot repair after installing windows , will it restore the dual boot functionality?

[image]

Comment: This is for installing Windows 7 but you may apply this for Win 8 too. >> [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/a/158319/179042) .. Remember, you will have to reinstate grub in order to get GRUB menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System for a guide to fixing grub after the install of windows.